# Weblogic clustering configuration

Tags: configuration, weblogic, cluster-computing, jdeveloper

I am developing an application with JDeveloper 11.1.1.6.0. I have a problem with my client application when I try to connect to a weblogic server from a cluster from within my application. A certain service runs on this server that I would like to call.

The situation is as follows:

There is a weblogic instance, whose configuration I cannot change at the moment. The weblogic instance has the following servers and clusters:

- Admin server AS - (runs on Machine M1) URL: A, port: 1  - URL for connection **t3://A:1**
- Cluster C containing:

  - Server S1 - (runs on Machine M1) URL: A, port: 2 - uses Database D1 - URL for connection **t3://A:2**
  - Server S2 - (runs on Machine M2) URL: B, port: 1 - uses Database D2 - URL for connection **t3://B:1**
  - Server S3 - (runs on Machine M2) URL: B, port: 2 - uses Database D2 - URL for connection **t3://B:2**

I am trying to connect to **t3://A:2** and not to the cluster or any of the other two servers. However, it works only every third time, maybe because of the three servers within the cluster. The cluster uses unicast for messaging and round-robin-affinity for load balancing.

I am trying to find out what causes this. Can I change something within the configuration of the weblogic where my client application runs (integrated or standalone)? Or must the configuration setup of the instance with the server cluster be changed?

Thank you in advance!

Best Regards

**(23.05.2013)**
EDIT:

We use a plain JNDI-Lookup to access an EJB on the remote server in the described scenario.

Context ctx = new InitialContext();

Object o = ctx.lookup(...)

...

jndi.properties:

java.naming.provider.url=t3://A:2
java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory

It seems to be possible to send the JNDI-Request to the right server by setting the property PIN_TO_PRIMARY_SERVER. Yet, subsequent ejb-requests are still routed to the whole cluster using round robin...

Can we do something on client-side to change this behavior to always address the specific server with the url t3://A:2?

Comment: Connecting directly like t3://A:2 should be working... do you get some sort of error message out when it fails you can post? I can hit WSDLs/proxies on a specific machine in a cluster without any problems.

Comment: There is no error message. I am just routed to the other two servers in a round robin. Every third time to the one that I want to connect to. I supporse it has to do with the fact that the admin server for the cluster and the server that I would like to reach reside on the same machine and URL (just the port number is different). Can it be that my integrated weblogic with my client application is connected erroneously to the cluster and therefore routed to one of the three?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe edit your post and put in some code on how you are connecting/what exactly you are trying to do? Is it JMS? Is it a WSDL? etc.

Comment: We have posted information about our context. Thanks.

Comment: Based on this info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jndi/jndi.html 

I'm not sure you'll be able to do what you want. "the context factory in WebLogic Server can choose whichever WebLogic Server in the cluster seems most appropriate for the client" Unless you target your specific deployment to a single node, weblogic will continue to round-robin you in the cluster.

Why do you need to use that specific server? If you only want the service on one node, change the targets.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after trying changing the InvocationContext environment properties, I found that I had very little luck. Instead I had to alter the **weblogic-ejb-jar.xml** for my stateless session bean.

```
String destination = "t3://node-alpha:2010";
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
env.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, destination );
// env.put( weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ENABLE_SERVER_AFFINITY, "true" );
// env.put( weblogic.jndi.WLContext.PIN_TO_PRIMARY_SERVER, "true" );
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext( env );

EJBHome home = (EJBHome) ctx.lookup( JNDI_REMOTE_SYSTEM_SF );
sf = SomeSf.class.cast( home.getClass().getMethod( "create" ).invoke( home ) );

// Check that we are hitting the right server node.
System.out.println( destination + " => " + sf );
```

Once you start a transaction, you shouldn't change servers, so I would create a stateless bean to receive the targeted calls and from there begin the work you intend to do. You can set a stateless bean as **not clusterable** in the `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`. You actually need to set both items listed below.

- `<home-is-clusterable>False</home-is-clusterable>`
- `<stateless-bean-is-clusterable>False</stateless-bean-is-clusterable>`

What this means is that when getting a reference through the initial context, is that the targeted server will give an instance of the reference to the stateless bean on that particular cluster node.

Using the servers

- node-alpha:2010
- node-alpha:2011
- node-beta:3010
- node-beta:3011

---

With `home-is-clusterable` & `stateless-bean-is-clusterable` set to *true*

Here the first entry is the server it is targeting, then the rest are for fail-over and/or the load balancing (e.g. round robin).

```
ClusterableRemoteRef(
3980825488277365621S:node-alpha:[2010,2010,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:MyDomain:node-alpha 
[
  3980825488277365621S:node-alpha:[2010,2010,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:MyDomain:node-alpha/338, 
  4236365235325235233S:node-alpha:[2011,2011,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:MyDomain:node-alpha/341, 
  1321244352376322432S:node-beta:[3010,3010,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:MyDomain:node-beta/342, 
  4317823667154133654S:node-beta:[3011,3011,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:MyDomain:node-beta/345
]
)/338
```

---

With `home-is-clusterable` & `stateless-bean-is-clusterable` set to *false*

```
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef - hostID: '-3980825488277365621S:node-alpha:[2010,2010,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:MyDomain:node-alpha', oid: '336', channel: 'null'
```

---

weblogic-ejb-jar.xml example below.

```
<weblogic-ejb-jar>
  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>SomeSf</ejb-name>
    <stateless-session-descriptor>
      <pool>
        <max-beans-in-free-pool>42</max-beans-in-free-pool>
      </pool>
      <stateless-clustering>
        <home-is-clusterable>false</home-is-clusterable>
        <stateless-bean-is-clusterable>false</stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
        <stateless-bean-methods-are-idempotent>true</stateless-bean-methods-are-idempotent>
      </stateless-clustering>
    </stateless-session-descriptor>
    <transaction-descriptor>
      <trans-timeout-seconds>20</trans-timeout-seconds>
    </transaction-descriptor>
    <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
    <jndi-name>SomeSf</jndi-name>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```